# Delete millions of rows based on ids in another table

Tags: mysql, delete

I have two tables on MySQL:

- `HISTORY_TABLE` (4 million rows) (column1 indexed)
- `EXTRACT_TABLE` (600K rows) (column1 indexed)

For every `EXTRACT_TABLE.column1` there are multiple `HISTORY_TABLE.column1` rows.

Objective: I want to delete all records that MATCH criteria:

```
HISTORY_TABLE.column1 = EXTRACT_TABLE.column1
```

I tried two different possibilities:

- Simple query that matches criteria (10 hours)
- Copying the `NOT EXISTS` rows into a new table (2days+)

I found via searching that deletion can be done in chunks with a stored procedure, but I don't know how.

Is there an example on how to do a cursor based on `EXTRACT_TABLE` to read in chunks and delete the other table? Or is there other way to accomplish my objective?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are deleting a large percentage of the table, it would be better to build a new table with the rows to keep:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
INSERT INTO new
    SELECT * FROM real
        LEFT JOIN extract  ON ...
        WHERE ... IS NULL;
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             new TO real;    -- swap tables (sort of)
DROP TABLE old;              -- clean up
```

Even that may be too invasive.  See the following for techniques for deleting "in chunks".  They won't finish "fast", but they won't have nearly as much impact on other activity.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

(`FOREIGN KEYs` and `TRIGGERs` are likely to cause trouble.)

Comment: Do you think LEFT JOIN will be faster than EXISTS (this took me forever)? let me know your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: @user3861709 - In some situations, the Optimizer will turn one into the other.  (I don't have the details.)  But such 'rewriting' would be done only if it is reasonably sure that it helps performance.

Comment: @user3861709 - What takes a long time is saving the old copies of millions of rows in case there is a crash and the data needs to be rolled back.  My `INSERT` approach avoids that.

Comment: @RickJames The only suggestion is that `RENAME` will fail if table has triggers.

Comment: @Kondybas - Thanks.  I updated my blog.